# Data not submitting to the database

Tags: angular, spring-boot

submit.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>User Registration</h2>
  
  <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstname" formControlName="firstname" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lastname" formControlName="lastname" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="userForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

submit.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { User } from '../user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-submit',
  templateUrl: './submit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./submit.component.css']
})
export class SubmitComponent implements OnInit {

  userForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    firstname: ['', Validators.required],
    lastname: ['', Validators.required],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    password: ['', Validators.required],
  });

  submittedUser: User | null = null;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Initialization logic if needed
  }

  transformUserToData(user: User): User {
    alert("hoi")
    const user1 = new User();
    user1.firstname = user.firstname;
    user1.lastname = user.lastname;
    user1.email = user.email;
    user1.password = user.password;
    return user1;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('Form validity:', this.userForm.valid);
    const user: User = this.userForm.value;
    const data = this.transformUserToData(user);
    this.userService.addUser(data).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.submittedUser = user; // Store the submitted user data
        this.userForm.reset();
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

user.service.ts

```
addUser(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.submitUrl, user);
}
```

backend code

```
@PostMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY POST Requests
public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestBody Data data) {

    Data n = new Data();
        
    n.setFirstname(data.getFirstname());
    n.setLastname(data.getLastname());
    n.setEmail(data.getEmail());
    n.setPassword(data.getPassword());
    userRepository.save(n);
    return "Saved";
}
```

Backend is working correctly. Data passed to the table using postman. but i couldn't submit data using frontend form. Data did not pass to table after submit. not show an error on terminal. help me to solve this error!

Comment: Check your network request from the Browser DevTools > Network tab, and see whether the request payload is correct as expected. And did you try to print out what is the result generated from `const data = this.transformUserToData(user)`?